# Azure Database cannot query table

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a database hosted on Azure that have 50 or so tables. There is one table with around 25 columns and 100,000 that I cannot query. I can't even query a single record, SQL Management Studio just shows the query running constantly.

I can query all of the other tables and permissions are OK.

Any Ideas on how I can troubleshoot?

Comment: Have you tried select top 1?  This would indicate that you have proper access and should return quickly if you do not use an order by.

Comment: Yes - tried a top 1 and nothing returns. Just keeps spinning.

Comment: Sounds like something was locking your table and your select was waiting to get a shared lock.

Comment: Is it an indexing problem? 100,000 probably isn't a lot of data but if you've no indexes, is it trying to scan the entire table and thus taking too long....as opposed to the other tables which do have an index of some sort?

Answer (score 2):

To resolve I thought I'd create a copy of the database to see if the copy had the same issue. Before making the copy, I made my production database Read Only.

After making the production database readonly, I could then query again. I then made my production database readwrite and that seem to resolve it.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: this helped you,but is not a valid approach (making database read only),you will have to run the query and see ,if it is blocked,are there are wait stats